# Flutter how to loop through multiple lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this code to loop through a list in flutter:

```
if (notificationDays.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedNotificationDays.length; i++) {
            createWaterReminderNotification(
                'Reminder',
                NotificationWeekAndTime(
                    dayOfTheWeek: int.parse(selectedNotificationDays[i]),
                    timeOfDay: remindertime));
          }
        }
```

But now I want to replace 'remindertime' with a list instead.
What can I do to loop through every item in this list?
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
if (notificationDays.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedNotificationDays.length; i++) {
            createWaterReminderNotification(
                'Reminder',
                NotificationWeekAndTime(
                    dayOfTheWeek: int.parse(selectedNotificationDays[i]),
                    timeOfDay: remindertime[i]));
          }
        }
```

'remindertime' is now a list of multiple 'timeOfDay'.
So, I got one list with days called 'selectedNotificationDays'. and one list with times called 'remindertime'.

I want to create a reminder on every day of selectedNotificationDays. and on that day I want to create this reminder on every time of reminder time.

like this:
Monday: (10.00 12.30 15.00)
Tuesday: (10.00 12.30 15.00)
Friday: (10.00 12.30 15.00)

Comment: could you explain what try to achieve with that? how do you plan to pick an item from remindertime list?

Comment: thanks , check Kentukyyo's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use another `for` loop. I also recommend replacing it with a `for in` for better readability. This is how you do it:

```
for(var selectedDay in selectedNotificationDays){
  for(var reminder in remindertime){
    createWaterReminderNotification(
      'Reminder',
      NotificationWeekAndTime(
        dayOfTheWeek: int.parse(selectedDay),
        timeOfDay: reminder,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: okay I get errors from this. Undefined name 'selectedDay'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: My bad, forgot to add the `var` before the variable names, i updated the sample code, try now